# "Analyze Code Coverage" option missing in Visual Studio 2017 Professional

Tags: .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, code-coverage

[image]

Is any options available to enable options in "Test->Analyze Code Coverage"?
Is another way to run the code coverage result?

Comment: Code Coverage is an [Enterprise Edition feature](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/compare/), not available in Professional.

Comment: For C# test coverage tools independent of VS, see https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/133/101

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you should post this an an answer and get some upvotes

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Code Coverage is an Enterprise Edition feature, not available in Professional.

Credits: @Damien_The_Unbeliever. Thanks for you answer in comments. Its helped me.

Comment: other options to get code coverage? 3rd party tools anything else that can be done

Answer (score 3):

simple code coverage statistics can be generated using the dotnet test command

```
 dotnet test myTestProject.csproj /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover
```

The opencover tool exists also as extension to visual studio
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=FortuneNgwenya.FineCodeCoverage

Comment: Where does it generate the result? I ran it, and it did not display any coverage result in the terminal, not did it create any report files.