# How to get CodeCoverage of tests running on VS2017 Professional Version 15.9.8?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, code-coverage

I want to find code coverage for methods in dlls to be tested.
Through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/using-code-coverage-to-determine-how-much-code-is-being-tested?view=vs-2017#requirements I understand that there should be menu for CodeCoverage in Test Explorer for VS2017. which I didin't find for my installed visual studio..

So what is process to find code coverage for VS 2017 professional version 15.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code coverage is a Enterprise feature that is not available for Professional version.

Duplicate of question ["Analyze Code Coverage" option missing in Visual Studio 2017 Professional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53096193/analyze-code-coverage-option-missing-in-visual-studio-2017-professional)

See version feature comparison here https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/compare/